# Highstock set different colors for different markers

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am tryting to develop a chart in Highstock where each  marker got an individual color.
When i push my Data in an Array like this :

```
      series.data.push([ 
       parseInt(Math.round(myDate.getTime())),
       parseInt(Math.round(myDate.getHours()))
       ]);
```

The Data is shown correctly, but when i try to set the color within each data-object like this, it doesn't work to show points.

```
          series.data.push([ {          
          x:   parseInt(Math.round(myDate.getTime())),
          y:   parseInt(Math.round(myDate.getHours())),
          marker:{fillColor: 'red'}} ]);
```

What am i missing?

**Update**: When i inspect it with firebug i can see that the series is set correctly within the chart object. so why does it now show up? :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved my problem. i had to change every marker in a for loop after i created the chart manually. it looks like this:

```
            chart2.series[0].data[i].update(
                {
                    y: chart2.series[0].data[i].y,
                    marker: {
                        enabled: true,
                        fillColor: myColor,
                        states: {
                            hover: {
                                enabled: true,
                                fillColor: "black"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                ,false,false);
    }

    chart2.redraw();
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
series.data.push([ {          
    x:   parseInt(Math.round(myDate.getTime())),
    y:   parseInt(Math.round(myDate.getHours())),
    marker:{
       enabled:true,
       fillColor:'red',
       states:{
        enabled:true,
        fillColor:'red' 
       }
    } 
} ]);
```

Comment: It didn't. Somehow the series disappeared when i tried to assign the x and y values like this.